# gi repository problem

Tags: package-management, python, software-center

When I try to run `software-center` I get this message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 25, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
ImportError: No module named repository
```

But I installed `gi` by

```
apt-get install python3-gi
```

but it says: `python3-gi is already the newest version.`